# How does the Web Audio API affect game development?

Tags: audio, web, web-audio-api

I'm trying to understand what the introduction of the Web Audio API has meant for the development of web based games.

Flash games can of course do some quite advanced audio processing, and for simpler games the audio element was maybe enough. But how has Web Audio API changed the game dev scene? In terms of what can be done, supported platforms and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Supported platforms are Chrome, Safari (with some prefixing caveats) and Firefox across all supported hardware/OS platforms; IE is working on development, though the longer tail of versions will take a while to deploy.

Web Audio enables very complex processing, but also very precise timing and multiple sounds; sound management is far, far easier than previously possible in HTML5.  In short, Web Audio dramatically improves the story for game audio development on the Web - which, of course, was one of its goals.